# Mic-->48v Heyden Phantom power (XLR)-->USB MIXER(XLRinput pin)

Tags: microphones, mixer

I have recently bought Audio Technica T2020 condenser mic
I have Behringer @502 USB Mixer, which Doesn't have "48v" phantom power instead is has 12V
I have external 48v Heyden Phantom power

Question:
I connect my MIC to external 48v Heyden Phantom through XLR cable
Next --> how do I connect to Behringer USB mixer in order to get the output to PC?

1] Is connection should be through the normal XLR cable I got with Behringer and connect from external 48v Heyden Phantom power in the socket provided in the mixer for mic OR

2]From external 48v Heyden Phantom power to Behringer USB mixer through other source like audio jacks in some other socket ?

Mic-->48v Heyden Phantom power (XLR)-->MIXER(XLR)
OR
Mic-->48v Heyden Phantom power (XLR)-->MIXER(AUDIO JACK)

Answer (score 3):

All XLR.
Mic to Hayden input.
Hayden output to desk.

Switch the phantom on before connecting anything.

[image]

Of course, a bit late to mention it now, but you could have got the 802 with proper phantom for less than the 502 + Hayden + extra cable ;)

Comment: - and, it only needs one power socket, too !

Answer (score 3):

It's worth trying out what happens when using 12V phantom power on your mic.  Some modern mics will actually generate their DC bias with a stepup converter and will work fine with 12V phantom power (the 12V standard can deliver quite more current than the 48V standard).  If the phantom power is used more or less directly for polarising the membrane, you still might get a signal, just a weaker one (at worst about 12dB loss) that might still work out for a tolerable signal-to-noise ratio.  Worth checking in comparison to budget phantom power boxes.